# How to append a vue props data to base path for an image source

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I've been working with Vue js and Laravel recently and I'm trying to get  an image from a source, the image source contains a base path and a vue prop data. But the problem is it returns an error stating that vue can not evaluate the expression. Any help will appreciated thanks

```
<a class="thumbLink"><img data-large="url('uploads/products/285x380/@{{ 
    itemDetails.product_image}}')" alt="img" class="img-responsive" 
    src="uploads/products/285x380/@{{ itemDetails.product_image) }}">
</a>
```

**Error message**

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body:  "uploads/products/285x380/"+(scope.itemDetails.product_image))

[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression ""uploads/products/285x380/"+(itemDetails.product_image))". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.

[Vue warn]: src="uploads/products/285x380/{{ itemDetails.product_image) }}": interpolation in "src" attribute will cause a 404 request. Use v-bind:src instead.

[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression ""uploads/products/285x380/"+(itemDetails.product_image))". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.

[Vue warn]: src="{{ itemDetails.product_image_lg }}": interpolation in "src" attribute will cause a 404 request. Use v-bind:src instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue cannot evaluate the expression because there's a syntax error. There's an unnecessary right bracket `)` in `@{{ itemDetails.product_image) }}`.

Also, there's a warning suggesting to use `v-bind:src` rather than interpolation.

Here's the code with both changes applied:

```
<a class="thumbLink">
  <img data-large="url('uploads/products/285x380/@{{  itemDetails.product_image}}')" 
       alt="img" 
       class="img-responsive" 
       :src="'uploads/products/285x380/' + itemDetails.product_image"
  >
</a>
```

---

Note that `:src` is shorthand for `v-bind:src`. Using `v-bind` causes the entire attribute to be evaluated as an expression.